# Компилятор не видит библиотеку

Tags: c, windows, mingw

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: При попытке RegSvr32]

При попытке компиляции (notepad++ и MinGW) появятся ошибка (скрин 3), хотя библиотека скачана. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Может надо сделать `regsvr32 C:\библиотека.длл`?

Comment: Ошибка появляется. :c

Comment: Ты запускал `regsvr32` из под `cmd`, которую запускал "от имени Администратора"?

Comment: Именно так и запускал!

Comment: Библиотеку не находит не компилятор, а ваше скомпилированное приложение.

Comment: А если либу положить в одну папку с exe-шником?

Comment: Напишите кто-нибудь нормальный ответ, этот вопрос я уже не то третий, не то четвёртый раз вижу за последние полгода.